# Can only ping OpenVPN server, not other guests (host-only network) on VPN network

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, vpn, vagrant

I installed OpenVPN server successfully on a server (X.X.X.X/32). Here is my OpenVPN config file:

```
port 1194
proto udp6
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh.pem
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/keys
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/keys/ca-crl.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/ta.key 0
tls-server
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256

server 10.109.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "route 192.168.59.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 5 30
compress lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
user nobody
group nogroup


status openvpn-status.log
status-version 1
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

On that server (X.X.X.X/32) I have a vagrant machine running in (host-only network) private network (vm.network 'private_network') with ip 192.168.59.2.

After connecting to OpenVPN from my localhost I would like to ping 192.168.59.2. I can only ping 192.168.59.1. As you can see Vagrant private network, and OpenVPN network is different. Please somebody can help with this issue? I'm also attaching my ovpn (snippet) file:

```
tls-client
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2

proto udp
remote X.X.X.X 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry 5
nobind
keepalive 5 30
compress lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
route-method exe
route-delay 2
key-direction 1
```

**EDIT1**:
I'm using 192.168.59.2 because vagrant shows a warning for `vagrant up`:

```
guest: You assigned a static IP ending in ".1" to this machine. ==> guest: This is very often used by the router and can cause the ==> guest: network to not work properly. If the network doesn't work ==> guest: properly, try changing this IP.
```

route -n output on Vagrant machine:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp0s3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.59.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s8
```

**EDIT2**:
Vagrant's machine ip changed to `192.168.59.1`. I also added the following line to ovpn file:
`route 192.168.59.0 255.255.255.0`
From localhost I can now ping `192.168.59.1` after connecting to vpn, but I'm still unable to ping `192.168.59.2`.

Comment: What is 192.168.59.1?

Comment: Please describe what `X.X.X.X/32` is supposed to represent.

Comment: If you want clients to be able to talk to each other on the VPN network, you generally need the `client-to-client` setting on the VPN server, I believe.

Comment: @Kusalananda the OP's VPN network is 10.109.0.0/16, so I don't think that's relevant here...?

Comment: @roaima In that case I misunderstood the question and the title (which I edited) should be updated to reflect the actual issue.

Comment: X.X.X.X/32 is given, we're renting a server from a company

Comment: Criaz91 please mention that in your question alongside the `x.x.x.x/32` so we know it's your public IP address. What's more interesting is what 192.168.59.1 is supposed to be.

Comment: Sure, if you create a vagrant machine with static ip ending .1 it shows a warning```==> guest: You assigned a static IP ending in ".1" to this machine.
==> guest: This is very often used by the router and can cause the
==> guest: network to not work properly. If the network doesn't work
==> guest: properly, try changing this IP.``` I'm going to try create with ip  192.168.59.1, and ```client-to-client``` setting.

Comment: Sigh. Please put your updates INTO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: Does the `192.168.59.2` knows how to contact your `10.109.0.0/16` OpenVPN network ? Cause, packets can reach the host, but if host doesn't know how to reply, then no response will be sent. Can you provide the output of a `route -n` on Vagrant machine ?

Comment: I think network ```192.168.59.2``` doesn't know about vpns network. Question updated with ```route - n``` output.

Comment: If I change Vagrant machine ip to ```192.168.59.1```, then I can ping it...but what about other ip's? (```192.168.59.2``` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. My vagrant machine (virtualbox provider) is located on private network with ip 192.168.59.2, on server (X.X.X.X/32).

If I would like to ping 192.168.59.2 from my localhost, after connecting to vpn, I need to execute the following command inside of the vagrant machine first:

```
ip route add 10.109.0.0/16 via 192.168.59.1 dev <VARGRANT_NETWORK_INTERFACE>
```

Where:

- 10.109.0.0 = openvpn network
- 192.168.59.1 = vboxnet* ip
- VARGRANT_NETWORK_INTERFACE = in my case it was `enp0s8`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable IP forwarding (routing) on your VPN server host, if you want your VPN to communicate with other hosts through the VPN server host:

```bsh
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/736274/openvpn-client-to-client/738558?noredirect=1#comment1109071_738558).

Comment: yes! IP forwarding needs to be enabled too.